# ruby why 0 || 1 is 0

Tags: ruby, boolean, bitwise-operators

AND operator return second value when the first is true, the first one  when it's false

```
1 && 2 ---> 2
0 && 1 ---> 0
```

why OR operation not return second value when the first one is false, but return the first one when it's true

```
0 || 1 ---> 0
1 || 0 ---> 1
```

Comment: `0 && 1` returns `1`, not `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby only evaluates as much as it needs to in an expression like this and then stops, what you are seeing returned is just the last part of the expression that it evaluated.
So for your && case, it always has to run right to the end in case a later clause returns false and which would cause the AND to be false.

And actually your example is wrong:

```
irb> 0 && 1
=> 1
```

Which is expected since 0 is truthy in Ruby, not as false like in C.

For the OR case, it can stop as soon as it hits anything that is truthy and doesn't need to bother with the rest.

```
0 || false      # => 0
false || 0      # => 0
false || 0 || 2 # => 0
```

If you want to force an expression like this to a boolean this is how you often see it done:

```
!!(expression)
!!(0 || 1)        => true
!!(nil || false)  => false
```

Comment: Every time I hear Ruby embraces the "principle of least surprise" I have to laugh.

Answer (score 3):

Both OR and AND are short-circuit evaluated, as soon as they know the value of the expression they give it to you. 
In Ruby both 0 and 1 are true, they are truthy values. So

`0 || 1 is 0`

because 0 is true. 
Just `nil || 1` or `false || 1` would return 1.

Answer (score 1):

|| is a logical operator, not a bitwise operator.  Unlike other languages for e.g C, 0 is not a "falsey" value in ruby.

Because || is a short-circuit logical operator, you have the following equivalent statement:

*defined value "0" || defined value "1"*

Which ruby is correctly evaluating as *truthy expression A* || *truthy expression B* and returning *truthy expression A* i.e. 0.

See here: https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362

for a good overview of "Truthy" and "Falsey" values in Python and Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on in here:

1. Unlike in other languages, in Ruby, `0` is truthy (which means it is evaluated a s true in a boolean context).
2. The OR operator in Ruby (`||`) shortcuts and returns the left argument if it is truthy.

Put these two together, and you get that `0 || 1` returns `0`